# Store text file in non-String array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to store lines from a text file into an array that isn't a String array. The return type is supposed to be a GO-array ( have created another class named "GO" with constructors and get-/set-methods which I'll use in other parts of the code.)

```
int rad = 0;  
GO [] list = new CD [rad]; 

public GO[] readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner read = new Scanner (new File(filename));
    while (read.hasNextLine()==true){
        rad++;
        read.nextLine();
    } read.close();

    read = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        //here the lines of the file should be stored in the "GO"array
        // but the declaration cannot convert string to GO[]
        list[i]=read.nextLine()
```

Comment: `==true` in logic is redundant. It is like `*1` or `+0`.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Edit: it's supposed to be " GO[] list = new GO[rad] "

Comment: the question is how do I store the input in the array

Comment: You can [edit] your question and fix any problems directly in it. We can't help you much if we don't understand the connection between the text you are reading and the GO class. So while you are editing, you should add an example of the content of the file, and the relevant parts of the GO class.

Comment: Either you shouldn't use that `GO` class or you need to teach it how to convert a `String` to a `GO`. It can not know that on it's own. E.g. change to `list[i]=convert(read.nextLine())` and add `private GO convert(String line) { */ do things with line and return the appropriate GO object */ }` where you implement that conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
class GO<T>{
   private T ref;

  public GO(T ref) {
    this.ref = ref;
  }

}
```

you should change your GO class to use generics and you can add value to Go Array with this approach.

```
 list[i] = new GO(read.nextLine());
```

by changing the class to generics . you can create an instance of Go class by passing any object to the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to parse the resulting `String` yourself and build a `GO` object out of it, which can be a separate method to keep things clean. Get the values of your object's variables and use your setters appropriately.

If your program is what's writing the file's contents, you'd be better off having `GO` implement `Serializeable` and saving/loading the state of the object itself instead of making text. If not, the above is your only option, really.

Comment: Actually, Java serialization is very bloated, and if you just want to persist the details of a particular class you are probably better off writing it yourself. Serialization is only good if you have a general framework that should support unknown classes, and even then there are substitutes for java serialization on the market which reduce its size and increase its portability.